# Notation from predicate transformer semantics textbook

Tags: notation, computer-science, predicate-logic

I'm reading my professor's text book on [predicate transformer semantics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_transformer_semantics) (an extension of Floyd-Hoare logic) and I stumbled upon the following notation, in this case describing a solution to the [maximum subarray problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem):

[image]

Does anybody know what the union-like symbol signifies or where it comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as the sigma symbol is used to denote a series: 
$$\sum_{k=1}^n a_k = a_i + a_2 + a_3 +\cdots+ a_n $$

So too, the big union symbol is used to denote an iteration of disjunctions:

$$\bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k = A_i \cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup\cdots\cup A_n $$

In this case we interpret the maximum of a disjunction as the maximum term. So:
$$\max\Big(\bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k\Big) = \max(A_i , A_2 , A_3 ,\ldots, A_n) $$

Hence:

$$\begin{align}
\text{result} & =
\max\Big(\bigcup_{A=1}^{L-1}\bigcup_{Z=A}^{L-1}\sum_{i=A}^Z a_i\Big)
\\
& = \max\Big(a_1, (a_1+a_2), \ldots, (a_A+\cdots+a_Z), \ldots, (a_{L-2}+a_{L-1}), a_{L-1}\Big)
\end{align}$$